# Figuring out the voltage at a point?

Tags: voltage, parallel, series

From the following diagram:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fBQslj.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

What would the voltage be at point b? 5V? And for point a would be 10V?

Likewise point a(10V) point b 15V?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fHeoGf.png)</sup>

Comment: "*voltage at point b*" means that the voltage at node b with respect to ground. And I see that node b is connected to ground. So what will be the voltage at b with respect to b?

Comment: @nidhin edited the schematics and question, thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Have you worked on this circuit before posting the question here because it looks pretty straight forward and if you apply KVL or superposition theorem you should be able to get the answer.

Comment: Yes, and could not figure it out really. Specially KVL for some reason could not figure out the voltage at point b&c.

Comment: @Key, b and c are directly connected through a wire, and therefore their voltage relative to the ground is the same. b & c belong to the same node.

Comment: Corrected that as well. What is the voltage for point B?

Comment: There are many ways of solving it. Maybe the shorter one would be to substitute the (5V in series 100 Ohms) by its norton equivalent (50mA parallel 100 Ohms) and apply nodal analysis at node b. That's a single equation to solve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay. Here goes the solution by applying Super-position to the circuit.

Case 1: Due to the primary supply PS: The equivalent circuit due to the supply PS is as shown below:

[image]

Apply voltage divider rule to get the voltage V' = 7.25 V

Case 2 : Due to the opposing voltage: The equivalent circuit is as shown below. (Observer the ground point carefully for the equivalent circuit)

[image]

The voltage obtained at the point b/c by applying voltage divider rule V"=-1.25V.

So the resultant voltage at the point b/c = V'+V"= 7.5-1.25= 6.25V

Similar calculations would lead you to results for the second case as shown below:

The answer would be V(case2)= V'+V"=7.5+1.25=8.75V

Comment: Thanks, I assumed the addition of that voltage source to the parallel circuit would cause problems or even short circuits, because its 5V in a parallel circuit that is at 10V